# Loading a query with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

```
function showUser(str) {
if (str=="") {
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","paginas.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I got this script from a website, it goes with this

```
<?php
$q = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',NULL,'ttrpg');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM content WHERE Pagina = '".$q."' ORDER BY ID ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<div class="container">';
  echo $row['Text'];
  echo "</div>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I also used this:

```
<body onload="showUser('Home')">
```

I didn't change the function's name because there's no need for that
The problem I'm having is that when I load the page, there's nothing showing up inside the div.
When I press a link with for example `onclick="showUser('Apple')"` the text inside the div DOES change, but to the text from `Home`, this text doesn't ever go away, except when I reload the page

Comment: Are you sure there's a row in the table where `Pagina = 'Home'`?

Comment: 2 rows, it does echo those

Comment: Why is the PHP script echoing `</table>` when it's not echoing table rows? I don't see how this could cause the problem you describe, but it's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a script on page load you can use

```
 <script>
   showUser('Home');
 </script>
```

just before

```
 </body> or </html> /* it will also work at the end of all html codes.*/
```

If you want to just print the query you executed in ajax file then you can simply use

```
  echo $sql="SELECT * FROM content WHERE Pagina = '".$q."' ORDER BY ID ASC";
```

you can also see the whole ajax headers, parameters sent and response using firefox's firebug or chrome 's developer tools using inspect element then going to nework it will show ajax request and response.

Additionally you can use print_r($_REQUEST) in your ajax php file.

EDITS: I have written code to work for your needs using ajax. This will call home pages content once the page loads from fetching record from table content. If you click on about button then it will fetch content of about page from content table.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="" content="">
    <style>.msg{ color:#ff0000;}
    #contentloader{ background-color:#fff; border:1px solid #333; padding:10px; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    function ajaxContentLoad(page){
            q = {
                'page':page,
            }
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                data:q,
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $("#msg").text("sending request to server...");
                },
                complete:function (){
                    $("#msg").text("request received and loaded");
                },
                success:function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {                       
                    $("#contentloader").html(result);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            })
}
$().ready(function(e){
    ajaxContentLoad('Home');
})

    </script>
    <body>
        <div style="padding: 20px; margin:20px auto; width:80%; background: #eee">
        <button id="btn1" value="Home" onclick="ajaxContentLoad('Home');">Home</button>
        <button id="btn1" value="About" onclick="ajaxContentLoad('About');">About</button>
        <p id="msg" class="msg"></p>

            <div id="contentloader">
                Content on page load
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is ajaxData.php file

```
    <?php
        $q = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['page']);

        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',admin,'demo');
        if (!$con) {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }

        mysqli_select_db($con,"demo");

        $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_content WHERE page = '".$q."' ORDER BY ID ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo '<div class="container">';
          echo $row['content'];
          echo "</div>";
        }

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Well, it DOES fix the problem of not showing anything when the page loads, but it keeps showing Home

Comment: If there is only one row then there is no need to loop it using while. Make sure your query returns any row by printing it's output  use print_r($row);

Comment: It does sometimes return multiple rows, I changed echo to print_r() but I still can't change the content by clicking any buttons

Comment: I use elements called "container" and sometimes I have more of those per page ;)
But, I still can't change the content by clicking any buttons :P